# How are kernel modules automatically inserted by systemd?

Tags: kernel-module, archlinux, systemd, udev

I am trying to find out how kernel modules are automatically inserted. I am using Arch Linux, so basically I am working with `systemd`.

After some research, I know there are at least 2 ways to insert kernel modules:

1. `systemd` has a unit called `systemd-modules-load.service`, which reads kernel module names in `/etc/modules-load.d/*.conf` (and the ones in `/run` and `/usr/lib`) ([systemd documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/modules-load.d.html)).
2. `udev` can handle kernel module automatically when devices are detected ([Arch Linux wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_modules#Automatic_module_handling)).

However, I failed to see how those work:

1. There are no config files in `/etc/modules-load.d/*.conf` (or the ones in `/run` or `/usr/lib`) on my system. Therefore it has nothing to load in `systemd-modules-load.service`.
2. There are some `modprobe` commands in `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d`, but not all of the kernel modules I see in `lsmod`.

For example, I have a `xfs` kernel module in the output of `lsmod`, but I can't find out the trigger point of inserting it. None of my filesystem are mounted with `xfs` (`cat /proc/mounts | grep xfs` shows nothing).

Is there any introduction or tutorial of how all this works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a very useful introduction on this topic: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Modalias

In brief, the secret is the mapping between `MODALIAS` in udev and `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.alias`.